# Unable to position the div content to center of page

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using angulars UI router to load each page separately. I have header navbar and sidebar inside header.html and main-content(dynamic) in login.html

The login html page is getting overlapped with sidebar and footer because it is loaded separately. How do I fix this? I applied wrapper(custom css) class but it didn't affect the layout at all.

Here the link: http://angularspring-management999.rhcloud.com/default.html

Sample code:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrap">

        <!--header-->
        <div ui-view="header"></div>

        <!--sidebar-->
        <div ui-view="sidebar"></div>

        <!--main content-->
        <div ui-view="content"></div>
    </div>

    <!--footer-->
    <div ui-view="footer"></div>
</body>
```

States:

```
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {

// For any unmatched url, redirect to /login
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/Login");

var header = {
    templateUrl: 'views/Header.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
    }
};

var sidebar = {
    templateUrl: 'views/SideBar.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
    }
};

var footer = {
    templateUrl: 'views/Footer.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
    }
};
// Now set up the states
$stateProvider
    .state('Login', {
        url: "/Login",
        views: {
            'header': header,
            'sidebar': sidebar,
            content: {
                templateUrl: 'views/Login.html',
                controller: function ($scope) {
                }
            },
            'footer': footer
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please include the *relevant* code in the question itself. Once that link goes bad, this question will be useless. See [mcve].

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The code is huge. i will try to trim down and update it soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't something like this work using bootstraps grid?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div ui-view="view-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <div ui-view="view-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've only ever used 1 ui-view element in my apps, and then created custom directives for this type of functionality.  But according to the docs your way should be fine.  Just be careful that sometimes ui-view can override certain template properties.

Comment: Is there a option of custom directive for this kind of requirement? I didn't know. I tried a similar approach as your code above but it didn't work.

Comment: Even without a custom directive, assuming bootstrap is included properly, you can always just make 1 ui-view and include any html within that view that you would like.  The custom directives are optional to keep things reusable and modular.

Comment: Thanks the above code worked. I wonder why it didn't work when I tried with col-md-6 wrapped with row

Comment: xs applies to all screen sizes.  md would only apply to screen sizes md and larger.  Therefore on a smaller screen using md would not work.

Comment: I guess if I am not wrong, a laptop would be md right?